# Fixed Header Scrolling Table - Align size issues

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to use this example [enter link description here](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/oVlgM) and make a nice table with fixed header and scrolling. I use 4 columns with different width which is like 10%, 50%, 30% and 10%. I am doing this, because I test the page view in different screen and this is the one that fits the best on all.

My problem is that all rows are not the same width with the header, which it is making align issues.

My HTML:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-fixed" id="example" style="width:100%; margin-top:20px;font-size:90%;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:10%;">#</th>
      <th style="width:50%;">Name</th>
      <th style="width:30%;">Enabled</th>
      <th style="width:10%;">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbody">
    <tr>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>Something here...</td> 
      <td>Yes</td> 
      <td><a href="###" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>Something here... part 2</td> 
      <td>No</td> 
      <td><a href="###" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>35</td>
      <td>Something here... part 3</td> 
      <td>Yes</td> 
      <td><a href="###" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th> 
      <th>Name</th> 
      <th>Enabled</th> 
      <th>Action</th> 
    </tr>                    
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

My css:

```
.table-fixed thead, .table-fixed tfoot {
width: 100%;
}

.table-fixed tbody {
height: 450px;
overflow-y: auto;
width: 100%;
padding-left:-5px;
}

.table-fixed thead, .table-fixed tbody, .table-fixed tfoot, .table-fixed tr, .table-fixed td, .table-fixed th {
display: block;
}

.table-fixed tbody td, .table-fixed thead > tr> th, .table-fixed tfoot > tr> th {
float: left;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
}
```

My tbody is now the same size as header, so the alignment is not correct. It is because of the size of the scroll bar.

Using Bootstrap 3. And only css if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add to your css (reason scrollbar needs room) This works:

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-default">

    <h4>
      Fixed Header Fixed height Scrolling Table
    </h4>

    <table class="table table-fixed">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="col-sm-1">#</th>
          <th class="col-sm-6">Name</th>
          <th class="col-sm-4">Enabled</th>
          <th class="col-sm-1">Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="col-sm-1">12</td>
          <td class="col-sm-6">Something here...</td>
          <td class="col-sm-4">Yes</td>
          <td class="col-sm-1"><a href="###" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>
                   <tr>
          <td class="col-sm-1">23</td>
          <td class="col-sm-6">Something here... part 2</td>
          <td class="col-sm-4">No</td>
          <td class="col-sm-1"><a href="###" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col-sm-1">35</td>
          <td class="col-sm-6">Something here... part 3</td>
          <td class="col-sm-4">Yes</td>
          <td class="col-sm-1"><a href="###" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col-sm-1">23</td>
          <td class="col-sm-6">Something here... part 2</td>
          <td class="col-sm-4">No</td>
          <td class="col-sm-1"><a href="###" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col-sm-1">35</td>
          <td class="col-sm-6">Something here... part 3</td>
          <td class="col-sm-4">Yes</td>
          <td class="col-sm-1"><a href="###" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col-sm-1">23</td>
          <td class="col-sm-6">Something here... part 2</td>
          <td class="col-sm-4">No</td>
          <td class="col-sm-1"><a href="###" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col-sm-1">35</td>
          <td class="col-sm-6">Something here... part 3</td>
          <td class="col-sm-4">Yes</td>
          <td class="col-sm-1"><a href="###" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col-sm-1">23</td>
          <td class="col-sm-6">Something here... part 2</td>
          <td class="col-sm-4">No</td>
          <td class="col-sm-1"><a href="###" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col-sm-1">35</td>
          <td class="col-sm-6">Something here... part 3</td>
          <td class="col-sm-4">Yes</td>
          <td class="col-sm-1"><a href="###" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th class="col-sm-1">#</th>
          <th class="col-sm-6">Name</th>
          <th class="col-sm-4">Enabled</th>
          <th class="col-sm-1">Action</th>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>

    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS: ==> width: 97%; does the trick

```
.table-fixed thead .table-fixed tfoot{
  width: 97%;
}
.table-fixed tbody {
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.table-fixed thead, .table-fixed tbody, .table-fixed tr, .table-fixed td, .table-fixed th {
  display: block;
}
.table-fixed tbody td, .table-fixed thead > tr> th {

  border-bottom-width: 0;
}
```

**EDIT** As we are inbootstrap we use classes and not % for width. we have a 12 grid to apply

Comment: I tried it but it is not align header with rows. See header,i have width in each column, not using col. If I run my code, my first column header width is 100px and in row is 97px. As you can understand, in my 2 last column I see more align issues.

Comment: need fix header, fix height and scrolling,

Comment: This is now with your texts - next time please apply your solution to my working example. Mark the answer as solverd and upvote if it fits Copy it to jsfiddle to see it working